# memory leak or some other problem in C++ and vector of strings

Tags: c++, string, memory, vector, memory-leaks

i keep getting memory leaks everytime I run this function in a loop:

```
uint32_t *padMessages(uint32_t *messages, const std::vector<std::string> &words) 
{
    uint32_t output[16];
    uint32_t size = words.size();
    uint32_t i, x, y;

    messages = (uint32_t *)malloc(16 * size * sizeof(uint32_t));

    x = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        padMessage((uint32_t *)_strdup(words[i].c_str()), output, strlen((const char *)words[i].c_str()) * 8);
        for(y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
            messages[x] = output[y];
            x++;
        }
    }

    return messages;
}
```

the code calling this function is

```
do {
    for(i=0 ; i<len ; i++) 
        temp[i] = letters[entry[i]];
    temp[len] = '\0';

    // store generated word to words vector
    words[array_count] = temp;

    // increment vector counter and total word count
    array_count++;
    word_count++;

    if(array_count == 100000) {
        // reinitialize array_count
        array_count = 0;

        // pad messages
        messages = padMessages(messages, words);

        free(messages);
        free(result);

        std::vector<std::string>().swap(words);
        words.resize(100000);
    }
    for(i=0 ; i<len && ++entry[i] == nbletters; i++) entry[i] = 0;
} while(i<len);
```

where is my memory leaking?

Comment: How do you know you have memory leaks?

Comment: Why are you bothering with `malloc`, `strdup`, `strlen` and the like if this is C++?

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
(uint32_t *)_strdup(words[i].c_str())
```

...allocates memory dynamically, and I don't see any matching call to `free` for the memory allocated.

I'd use `std::string` throughout.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `strdup` in the loop in the top function and you are never `free`'ing those strings you are allocating.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the memory allocated by _strdup isn't freed.